# Change color of DataGrid in flash cs4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using the as3 DataGrid component in a flash project and I want to change the color from black on white to white on black but can't find how to change the colors of the DataGrid control. Can anyone help?

This is the flash component, I'm not using flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/datagrid_pt3/#section12

Sorry for the 1 year delay!